# Doesn't the non-commutivity of $x$ and $p$ complicate the measurement of a quantum system's (e.g.) Energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, operators, commutator, quantum-measurements

A classical system is parameterized by $x$ and $p$ coordinates, and so any other observable -- such as energy -- is some function $E(x,p)$ of them.  I assume, then, that to measure the energy one must measure $x$ as well as $p$ and then place them into the formula.

Nothing analogous can hold for a quantum system's energy.  As is well known, I can measure $x$ and then I can measure $p$, but I *cannot* construe those values as having jointly obtained at any common time.  It would be nonsense to put them both into any formula.

Quantum "measurement" is hopelessly idealized in the standard undergrad treatment, and so I try to imagine the actual procedure someone would make use of to learn the energy.  Yet I cannot.  The argument above would show (if it succeeds) that a measurement of energy would have to access it "directly" (whatever that means), instead of as a function of other non-commuting quantities.

Does this make energy a more fundamental thing in QM than it was in CM?  In CM you can just say "Oh energy is some conserved function, and obviously it's handy to know conserved functions.  That's all it is."

Comment: I can't write an answer because I don't know what you mean by more fundamental, but I can validate your reasoning: a measurement of energy must access it "directly," as you explained. The main reason we call the system's total energy an observable is because we typically use relatively concise rules to specify which operators are observables (like the lazy rule that *all* self-adjoint operators are observables), and the operator that generates time-translations (energy) typically satisfies those rules, so we include it for simplicity even if we don't actually know how to *measure* it.

Comment: Surely, though, experimentalists have claimed to have "measured a quantum system's energy"?  How did they do that?

Comment: What I mean by "fundamental" is that, in the quantum case, it seems there is no reduction of the energy to a function of other variables. (Well, there is an operator expression for the energy-operator in terms of position/momentum operators. But I explained already what I mean.) This gives energy an "irreducible" character that it didn't seem to have in CM, where you always can use your knowledge of position/momentum values to get knowledge of the energy value.

Comment: Yes, there are special cases and special senses in which a system's energy can be measured. My comment was coming from a more general perspective: something may be called an observable just for mathematical convenience, even if we don't actually have a way to measure it, and this is often (not always) the case for the total-energy observable. I'm also thinking of complicated systems, like systems with lots and lots of particles, not just one particle. Not an answer, just a perspective.

Comment: By that definition of "fundamental," I think it's fair to say that many (all?) observables in QM, such as energy, do have a more fundamental status in that sense, because we can often express observables in terms of other observables that don't all commute with each other, so measuring all of its parts (in some order) does not give the same information as measuring the whole, or conversely.

Comment: I see.  That's a satisfactory answer (that we don't really measure energy very often) but it leaves me confused because my impression was that experimentalists claim to measure energy all the time.  Admittedly I have zero contact with experimental practice.

Comment: Maybe this will help (?): When using quantum theory (QT), we usually just declare that an observable has been measured, instead of modeling the measurement process itself. We *can* model it, but somewhere downstream we still have to just declare that other observables have been measured so that we can extract the results of the measurement we explicitly modeled. In QT, measurement is both a physical process and a primitive input. Nobody is satisfied with that, but nobody knows what to do about it, and the theory works great in spite of it. It's amazing and frustrating at the same time. :)

Comment: Yes, I see, thank you.  The brief overview in your second sentence sounds similar to the conclusion I tried to explain in my two comments to wyphan's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In QM, performing a measurement perturbs the system with the probe you're measuring with. The state of the system before and after the measurement are different.

For example, you want to measure the energy of the system using a photon. Before the measurement the system was in the ground state. You probe the system with a single photon, say from a laser source, which is absorbed by the system. The system is now in an excited state. After some time, the system returns to the ground state, releasing a photon, which is then detected by your detector.
Your measurement data is then whether a photon is detected at the detector (which confirms that the excited state was available to the system), the energy of the photon that was detected (which can be different from your probe, in the case of phosphorescence and fluorescence), and the time elapsed between the photon you sent out and the photon you detect. All three measurements are limited by your experimental setup (for instance, sensitivity of the detector).

Say, instead of measuring the energy, you want to measure the momentum using electron scattering. You shoot an electron beam to the system (because using a single electron might not be enough due to the finite cross-section). The electron beam is then scattered by both the ions and electrons in the system, which at the same time also perturbs the electronic density of the system. You then use an analyzer to separate the scattered electrons with different momenta. Your measurement data is then the number of electrons that are scattered at a specific solid angle (where you place your analyzer), and the magnitude of the momentum of the analyzed electron (higher momentum = higher deflection in the analyzer). From there, you can analyze the composition of the system. This measurement technique is in common use in experimental condensed matter to investigate atomic structures, known as [low-energy electron diffraction (LEED)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-energy_electron_diffraction).

Furthermore, if the system was in an entangled state before the measurement, the measurement collapses the system into a single eigenstate. The fact that measurement is a non-reversible process is one of the basic tenets of quantum information.

Comment: Okay, so to put this in my own terms: what we measured really are some positions/momenta of an auxiliary system (scattered photon, electron beam, etc) and then infer the energy of the primary system with help from the theoretical model onhand.  After doing so, it is a tenet of QM that we must place the primary system into an eigenstate of a certain prescribed operator -- namely, the energy operator.

Comment: If we measure the primary system (B) indirectly through the position/momentum of auxiliary system (A), the dogma of QM [taken narrowly] only instructs us to set A into a position/momentum eigenstate.  Since we also want to construe this as a measurement of B, we will want to set B in some eigenstate as well.  Eigenstate of what?  Our model of the interaction will have to answer that somehow, and my guess is as follows: if the quantity we are inferring about B is classically conserved by a [classical] symmetry, we should associate it to the operator that generates that same [quantum] symmetry.