# How do we measure arbitrary observables in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observables, quantum-measurements

The postulate of quantum mechanics say that

> The operators corresponding to the dependent variable $\omega(x,p)$ are given Hermitian operators $\Omega(X,P)=\omega(x\rightarrow X,p\rightarrow P)$.

Now in classical mechanics, it's clear that if you know $x$ and $p$, then you just need to put the values of these canonical variables to get the value of any arbitrary variable.

But in quantum mechanics, this method doesn't work! Now I want to know

*How do we measure any observable in quantum mechanics?*

---

I was reading R.Shankar's book in which he said

> One way to measure the momentum of the particle is by *Compton scattering*, in which a photon of definite momentum bounces off the particle

And one measurement that I have read was from the *Stern-Gerlach experiment* that is used to measure the angular momentum.

That gives a sense that we have different setups for measuring different observable, so what we do for an arbitrary observable?

Comment: What do you mean by an 'arbitrary observable'? Experiments have to be tailored to the observable you want to measure; it is highly dependent on the nature of the particular observable you are interested in.

Comment: I asked a similar question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/598325/doesnt-the-non-commutivity-of-x-and-p-complicate-the-measurement-of-a-quant?noredirect=1#comment1347109_598325

Comment: By arbitrary observable, I mean any observable $\Omega(X,P)$.